# change of web.config of a sharepoint webn part

Tags: android-studio, sharepoint

I have a sharepoint webparts developed using visual studio and deployed to sharepoint. I need to change some settings in the web.config without redeploying everythimg.
How can I do?

Answer (score 0):

Web.config modification is possible using SPWebService.ApplyWebConfigModifications method.

It is worth mentioning that changes to the web.config file will trigger application pool recycling.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/ms475439(v=office.14)

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/bb861909(v=office.14)